# get encryption key from encrypted and decrypted data

Tags: encryption, aes

I used `encfs` to encrypt some important files on my system, but sadly I forget the encryption key. I still have a version of some of the the encrypted files.

Is there there a way to get the encryption key if I have the two versions of the file (the encrypted and decrypted one), so I can use this key the get the rest of my files?

`encfs` uses `ssl/aes` 256 key size

Comment: Realistically, no. What you want is a "known plaintext" attack, and no computionally feasible attack of that kind is publicly known against AES.

Comment: ok thank you very much .. so my files are lost and there is nothing to do

Comment: Unluckily, that's the very purprose of encryption. Unless you can remember or guess the password/key, there's no realistic way of recovering the files.

Comment: ok last question . i created a python code to do a brute force attack (i still remember parts of the password)  i generated a list of password that i think maybe the key what's the easiest what to check if the key is right (i noticed there is a a hash in the .encfs6.xml that i can compare against)

Comment: Easiest way is to try and decrypt a file of which you know that it contains a lot of entropy (say, a source file). Such a file would (if not encrypted) compress very well with e.g. `gzip`. If `gzip` is able to compress the decrypted file by more than 50% or so, you've found your key. That's a very easy kind of "statistical modelling" using built-in tools :-)

Comment: ok; thank you again i didn't understand  much of what u said , i'll try to do some research on it ... thank you again  for your time

Comment: It's actually really easy. Encrypted data is "random looking rubbish". The same is true for data that you decrypted using a bad key. Since "random rubbish" does not compress well (or, at all) but plaintext does, this can be used to distinguish between the two. Once you get to compress whatever you decrypted in any significant manner, it's highly likely that the key you used was the good one.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good thought! With some encryption schemes, it is indeed possible to view what the 'difference' is and apply this difference to other encrypted files. This is a known (classic) weakness in PKZIP encryption.

Unfortunately for your situation, AES protects against this. Getting files back using this attack is not possible.

Imagine you were not telling the truth, but you're a criminal who obtained access to one of the files stored on the encfs legitimately. Maybe someone stored their resumé there which they also sent out. Now this criminal would have access to all the other files on the encfs as well. That's why this protection exists: it makes the encryption stronger.